# Customize Angular Material component dimensions

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to customize the sizing of Angular Material buttons (i.e. padding). The definition of these values comes from a variable called `$mat-button-padding` in [_button-base.scss](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/_button-base.scss). However, it is directly included in the `button.ts`. Is there a possibility to adjust this value?

I already tried overriding it before including the material theme (as the variable is defined using `!default`), but it has no effect since the styles are directly included in the button component. Are there any other options except overriding it by hand and generating duplicate styles (basically an additional css definition that overrides the button styles)?

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just override the defined style. If you are not happy with the padding you have to define what you want somewhere?  Something like (not tested) ::ng-deep .mat-button {padding: 0 27px!important}.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add own class in "mat-button" element like below and you can apply your own css.

<button mat-stroked-button 
color="primary" 
class="common-button">Button</button>

.common-button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: You are right, that is a solution. But I was hoping to come up with one that does not require overrides or additional CSS but rather have the correct CSS generated in the first place.